# Google Schema Violation Error with scope parameter

Tags: scope, google-api, gmail-api, google-email-settings-api

I have a scenario here that I am creating an application which I need to get into connection with Google API Server. Upon Authorization request I encounter an error that says  The problem is an XML schema violation error.
The line question (no. 47 of the Mule configuration file) is this:

```
<oauth2:authorization-request 
    authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" 
    localAuthorizationUrl="https://localhost:8082/authorization" 
    scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"
/>
```

Mule's OAuth2 schema doesn't seem to allow a scope parameter to be included in an authorization-request element.  Yet, when removed,I get a response of:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: scope"
}
```

I've carefully followed and implemented the instructions in the Google documents but still failures appears to my end. 
Looking forward to whatever suggestions.

Comment: Did you check the proper [scope](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) that you need to your schema? Especially the custom user schema.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it and it matches the Google API Documentation.But still gives me the same issue.